# JUnit5 tapestry messages NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, tapestry, junit5

I have a few tests using tapestry messages with Mockito like that:

```
@Test
void messageTest(@Mock Messages msg1) { 
    Set<String> res = new HashSet<>();
    res.add("1");
    res.add("2");
    Mockito.lenient().when(msg1.getKeys()).thenReturn(res);
    // ...
```

This works fine when running the test on it's own, but when running all tests for a package (or the whole project) in IntelliJ, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Messages.getKeys()Ljava/util/Set;
```

and the test fails. I'm pretty sure it's not because of Mockito, as I didn't use it before and experienced the same problem.

---

I know that the example I provided isn't enough to replicate the problem (I'm currently failing myself to replicate the problem). The problem occurs everywhere in my project (i.e. even if I create a test class in another module), but not outside of it. Furthermore the problem doesn't occur for other methods (e.g. `lenient().when(messages.format("")).thenReturn(null);`) of `Messages`.

Also note that the problem persists in a way shorter way:

```
when(messages.getKeys());
```

(I used `import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;`).

However, the whole exception might be of some help to you:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Messages.getKeys()Ljava/util/Set;

    at de.....MessagesUtilImplTest.getKeyToMessage(MessagesUtilImplTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a dependency problem. Note that the `org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Messages.getKeys()` method exists since version 5.4. If you load an older version the method does not exist. You probably have a problem with your project configuration (e.g. gradle dependency settings) or the setup (`@Before`) of your test suite.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I use maven, but that won't be relevant. I'll look into my dependencies, but I didn't use a setup for my test suite - what should be in there?

Comment: I checked all my dependencies and made sure that all tapestry dependencies are on the same version (5.4.4). I also checked whether another dependency has a dependency on tapestry (which wasn't the case). I can't think of something else that might be wrong in the project configuration.

Comment: Ok so the more obvious mistakes are eliminated. I guess your code snippet might not be enough to evaluate what happens.

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: @MetaColon Likely a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Slaw I'm currently trying to do this, however it seems to be hard to replicate (I created a test project with and created this scenario, but there's no error thrown). As I don't know _what's_ causing the error, I don't know what to add to the minimal example, so as to create a verifiable example.

Comment: @MetaColon The MCVE link gives some strategies for making the example minimal. Since using the first strategy (i.e. "restarting from scratch") isn't working, try using the second strategy (i.e. "divide and conquer"). Though if your code is large doing so might be tedious/time consuming.